# Rails 6 (webpack) Inline Javascript: refer to asset_pack_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have inline script which needs to refer to my images. Simply adding image pack tag to the image does not work as it does not point to the correct path.

**Example**

```
let icon = {
  url: '<%= image_pack_tag('map/icon.svg') %>'
}
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Jeroen

Comment: You need to use '`<%= raw image_pack_tag('map/icon.svg') %>'` as Rails will automatically escape the string.

Comment: This returns the same which cannot be rendered:

url: '<img src="/packs/media/images/map/icon-d601882354769586efab3d5ddd7767fb.svg" />',